# What should be the input_shape here?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I don't have much experience in posting questions to Stack Overflow. Pardon my mistakes. I will try to be thorough.

I have two numpy arrays :

1. X with shape (78300, 90, 90).
2. y with shape (78300, 29)

- X is an array of black and white images with height and width (90, 90).
- y is the corresponding encoded class labels for X. (encoded as in
  `y = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels)` )

I am trying to train the following CNN on this data.

```
from tensorflow.keras import utils
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(90, 90, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(29, activation='softmax'))
```

I am receiving the following error on running

```
n_classes = 29
batch = 64
epochs = 5
learning_rate = 0.001

adam = Adam(lr=learning_rate)

model.compile(optimizer=adam,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

cp_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=os.path.join("/output_dir", "result_folder"),
                              save_weights_only=True,
                              verbose=1)

history = model.fit(x,
                    y,
                    batch_size=batch,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_split=0.1,
                    shuffle=True,verbose=1,
                   callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 90, 90]`

I cannot figure out what is going wrong. **Please help me.** Also, if you could link a documentation/article/blog post/video that will help me understand the nuances of the input shape in layers, that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shape should be (78300, 90, 90, 1).

Reshape `x` (add a dimension):

```
x = x[..., tf.newaxis]
```

Comment: what is `tf.newshape`? i can't find documentation for that

Comment: @NicolasGervais it is typo. Sorry. See edits

Comment: I used `x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)` . Turns out black and white images doesn't have the shape for the channel. Thanks for the help. I selected this answer as the correct one.